# How to make sure elasticsearch is using the analyzers defined on the mappings?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an index in elasticsearch with several custom analyzers for specific fields. Example:

```js
"titulo" : {
   "type" : "string",
   "index_analyzer" : "analyzer_titulo",
   "search_analyzer" : "analyzer_titulo"
}
```

`analyzer_titulo` is this:

```
"analyzer_titulo":{
    "filter":[
        "standard",
        "lowercase",
        "asciifolding",
        "stop_filter",
        "filter_shingle",
        "stemmer_filter"
    ],
    "char_filter":[
        "html_strip"
    ],
    "tokenizer":"standard"
}
```

However when i try to use the `_analyze` api to test the analyzer for this field elasticsearch seems to ignore the custom analyzer:
[image: kopf analysis tab]

As you can see both results are different but, if my understanding is correct, they should be the same.

What i am missing here? Is there a way to use the `_explain` api to see what analyzer is used?

PS: unfortunately i can't post my full mappings (company policy) but i only have one index and one type.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with the tool you're using to test your analyser (don't know why it's not working), but what you can do is run a query that returns the values sitting in the index

```
curl 'http://localhost:9200/myindex/livros/_search?pretty=true' -d '{
    "query" : {
        "match_all" : { }
    },
    "script_fields": {
        "terms" : {
            "script": "doc[field].values",
            "params": {
                "field": "titulo"
            }
        }
    }
}'
```

If your type has many documents in it, then you'll want to change the `match_all :{}` to something more specific.